# Full calendar highlight only empty / available free slots

Tags: javascript, view, fullcalendar

I'm using [`fullcalendar`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/) in my application. Here is the part of my working code

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
    views: {
        week: {
            titleFormat: 'D MMM YYYY',
            columnFormat: 'ddd D'
        },
        day: {
            titleFormat: 'D MMMM YYYY',
            columnFormat: 'dddd D'
        }
    },
    firstDay: 1,
    nowIndicator: true,
    weekNumberCalculation: 1,
    slotLabelFormat: 'HH:mm',
    slotLabelInterval: '00:10',
    events: events_arr,
});
```

which renders the calendar perfectly. The question is, Is there a way to highlight only the available slots to the user? I mean if there is an event today from 10:00 to 11:00, I need to show the slots except the time 10:00 to 11:00.

I referred the documentation, but nothing found. If anybody knows how to highlight the available slot, please share your thoughts.

Comment: A lot of people find the Background Events concept is useful for this kind of thing. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/Background_Events/

Comment: This is really interesting. @ADyson Thanks for that